# Understanding and using project specific .rvmrc rvm config files

Tags: ruby, rvm

Just getting started with Ruby.

I am trying to use rvm. Now, for Project A I am trying to specify a specify Ruby version and a gemset.

```
$ cat projecta/.rvmrc
rvm 1.8.7@projecta
```

My understanding is that the part before @ specifies the Ruby version and the the part after @ specifies the gemset name. A gemset IMU is to provide a project specific isolated location where you can install gems.

After I check-in this project, what can I do to automate the process of creating the gemset and installing the correct Ruby version for someone else checking the project out at a later date?

Please suggest appropriate alternatives, since I am just getting started with Ruby today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Old Way

to make sure gemset / ruby is available use this `.rvmrc`:

```
rvm use 1.8.7@projecta --install --create
```

It will install ruby if missing and create gemset if missing.

And a special note, please do not use 1.8.7, it's deprecated ruby, with almost no support (security patches till half of 2013), you should stick with latest available ruby:

```
rvm use ruby
```

which at this time is: 1.9.3-p194

Comment: thanks, I am using 1.9.3. I am not sure whey i put 1.8.7 for this example.

Answer (score 2):

#### Add On-Demand Syntax

Your syntax won't work as written. If you want to force people to compile rubies and create gemsets on demand, rather than being warned when things don't exist, you want a project *.rvmrc* file like this:

```
# Compile rubies on demand.
rvm_install_on_use_flag=1

# Create gemsets on demand.
rvm_gemset_create_on_use_flag=1

# Use ruby-1.8.7 while in project tree.
rvm use 1.8.7

# Use gemset "projecta" while in project tree.
rvm gemset use projecta
```

There are certainly other ways to do it, but this way makes everything explicit, and you can comment out individual lines if you need to do so.

#### See Also

https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc/

Comment: @mpapis There was a lot of great information in your edit, but it made the intent of my answer much less clear. While I agree there are many ways to solve this particular issue, the answer I provided works well, is easy to explain, and is largely self-documenting. Anyone who wants to do something more complex should certainly look at https://rvm.io/workflow/projects/#ruby-versions and the rest of the RVM site for other approaches to this issue. Thanks for being interested enough in the issue to offer such a comprehensive edit!

Comment: the issue with your answer is that you misuse the variables, they are meant to be in `~/.rvmrc` / `/etc/rvmrc` using them in project `.rvmrc` will give exactly the same result as mine answer.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. As a personal preference I like the concise syntax, so I marked the other answer.

Comment: update, using this variables in project `.rvmrc` will influence other projects - this variables will be loaded into the shell and any command like `rvm use` will install ruby if it is not available.

Comment: @mpapis I haven't personally found this to be an issue in practice, but one can always set `rvm_project_rvmrc_default=1` to prevent this behavior if it becomes a problem.

Comment: you are missing the point, consider `projecta/.rvmrc` with those variables exported and `projectb/.rvmrc` with only `rvm use 1.8.6`, now when `1.8.6` is not installed, this sequence: `cd projecta; cd ../projectb` will triger installation of `1.8.6` - this is unwanted behavior, and why the `--install` flag is preferred over it.